# In Text web part, the Move Image button does nothing

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-pages, image

I'm a new SharePoint Online (modern experience) user, so maybe I'm doing something wrong…

In a Text web part, after adding an image (using the button on the toolbar), I can click on the image to select it.  Context buttons appear at the top, and seem to work fine.  A "Move image" icon also appears near the left margin; I can find no combination of mouse actions on that icon that have any effect whatsoever.

I have verified this problem using Firefox, Chrome, and Safari.  All pages I have edited so far were migrated from a Confluence wiki.  Could the migration have somehow broken page editing?

Edit to posting, more detail:

1. In a brand new page in the same site, moving image works pretty much as I would expect.  The drag handle is the first item on the toolbar that appears at the top of the selected image, and has hover-text "Drag image".  While dragging, the mouse icon is sometimes (about 30% of the time) joined by a small grey globe.
2. A new image added to a migrated page can be moved with the handle.  The drag handle is separate from the toolbar (left margin or on image, depending on alignment), and has hover-text "Click and drag to move".  While dragging, mouse is instead joined by a blue, section-width horizontal line.  This is true in either existing or new Text web part.
3. Migrated images have a drag handle in the same location as #2, but hover text is "Move image".  Dragging handle has no effect.
4. If a migrated image is deleted and re-inserted, it temporarily gains abilities in #2, but only for that image and not others in the web part.  After an indeterminate amount of further editing elsewhere in the page, that image reverts to behavior #3. Saving the page and re-editing reverts all images to behavior #3.

Comment: What happens when you create a new site page from SharePoint? Is it working fine in that case?

Comment: Thanks for looking in, @GaneshSanap.  More info added in posting.